AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'concat'
I have written some simple code to iterate through a group of lists I am analyzing, and I discovered this error - module 'numpy' has no attribute 'concat', in this case would there be a solution?
I'm using this code:
import numpy as pd

# The stocks we'll use for this analysis:

tech_list = ['AMZN', 'NVDA', 'VOO', 'QQQ']

# Set up End and Start times for data grab
tech_list = ['AMZN', 'NVDA', 'VOO', 'QQQ']


end = datetime.now()
start = datetime(end.year - 1, end.month, end.day)


for stock in tech_list:
    globals()[stock] = yf.download(stock, start, end)


company_list = [AMZN, NVDA, VOO, QQQ]
company_name = ["AMAZON", "NVIDIA", "Vanguard S&P 500", "Invesco QQQ"]


for company, com_name in zip(company_list, company_name):
    company["company_name"] = com_name

df = pd.concat(company_list, axis=0)
df.tail(10)

This gives me:
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'concat'


Did you perhaps do import numpy as pd instead of import pandas as pd? (We need a full traceback btw, not just the error itself.)

If there's another problem and you can't solve it despite doing thorough research, feel free to ask another question!

Yes, Thanks @Andrew Yim.
